# char* Input function Causes Seg Fault

Tags: c++

Working on an assignment about Abstract Base classes, I'm running into a segment fault when I execute the getInput function I created in the addRecord function. I've tried a variety of methods for getting the user input for the name of the Employee/Student, however I keep running into issues with it.

**getInput:**

```
char* getInput(std::string message)
{
    char* name;
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    std::cin.getline(name, INT_MAX);
    return name;
}
```

**addRecord:**

```
/*
 * addRecord(vecotr<base*>& v)
 *
 * Ask the user which type of record they want to add, an employee or student. Once
 * they have made their selection, dynamically create a new pointer of the selected
 * type of record and have them fill out the record's members via its set methods,
 * then add it to the vector using the vector method .push_back().
*/
void addRecord(std::vector<Base*>& v)
{
    std::cout << "--Records to Create--" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.) Student Record" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2.) Employee Record" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please select from the above options: ";
    int sel = intInputLoop(1, 2);
    clearConsole();
    if (sel == 1)
    {
        char* name;
        /*
        std::cout << "Record Type: Student" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        std::cin.getline(name, INT_MAX);
        */
        name = getInput("What is the Student's name? ");
        float gradePointAverage = (float)intInputLoop(0, 4);
        Student student = Student();
        student.setName(name);
        student.setGradePointAverage(gradePointAverage);
        Base* bp = &student;
        v.push_back(bp);
        std::cout << "Added Student record for " << name << " with a grade point average of " << gradePointAverage << std::endl;
        delete name;
    }
    else
    {
        char* name;
        std::cout << "Record Type: Employee" << std::endl;
        name = getInput("What is the Employee's name? ");
        std::cout << "What is the Employee's salary? ";
        int salary = intInputLoop(0, 0);
        Employee employee = Employee();
        employee.setName(name);
        employee.setSalary(salary);
        Base* bp = &employee;
        v.push_back(bp);
        std::cout << "Added Employee record for " << name << " with a salary of " << salary << std::endl;
        delete name;
    }

}
```

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `name` is a pointer to `char`. Ask yourself "What is the valid memory address held (pointed to) by the pointer?" Unless you can answer that question for every raw pointer you use -- you will likely find yourself running into the same problem. `name` is an uninitialized pointer that holds an unknown (garbage) address. (e.g. is points nowehere in particular - just to an address made up of whatever numbers happened to be in memory at the time). When you attempt to write to that address, odds are it is outside the range of valid addresses - so boom! SegFault.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* name;
```

This declares a pointer, to an indeterminate number of `char` values. Who knows how many of them there are. It could be just one, very lonely `char`, sitting there, all by itself with nobody to play with. It could be a million, an entire city of `char`s. It's completely unspecified, nobody knows; that's because the pointer is completely uninitialized. Nothing in C++ happens automatically. If you intend to use a pointer, it must, well, point somewhere valid before you can use that pointer.

```
    std::cin.getline(name, INT_MAX);
```

This call to `getline` reads input into a pointer. The pointer must point to ***valid*** memory. Since the pointer is uninitialized, this is undefined behavior, and is the reason for your crash.

Since your intent here is to use C++, the simplest solution is to use a C++ class that just happens to handle all the memory management for you: `std::string`:

```
std::string name;

std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

You'll need to replace all old-fashioned `char *` pointers, which is what you would use if you were writing C code, with `std::string`. After all: this is C++, not C.

Comment: So for this assignment I'm required to use a char*, otherwise I would be using a string. I'm trying to initialize the char* with the following:

char *name = NULL;

However it doesn't seem to work. I tried converting a char name[32] to a pointer, but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: @SageHopkins - an array is converted to a pointer to the first element whenever you access it [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2). With `char name[32];`, on access`name` is a pointer to the 1st character in the array. Additionally, as used `char* name;` in `getInput()` is local to the function. The only way a raw pointer can be validly returned would be to allocate storage and return a pointer to the new block of allocated memory.  Sam's comment about writing C++ instead of C should be taken to heart.

Comment: Before you were given this programming assignment I would expect that the fundamental concepts that are needed to implement your programming task would be explained by your instructor: how pointers work, whether you are expected to use arrays or dynamically allocated buffers, or some other approach that involves pointers. I don't know what your instructor told you and how, exactly, your program should work. I can only explain the crash, and why. In C++ you must ensure that all pointers are valid before using them. Only you can figure out how to do that, given all your real requirements.